# Blackberry 10: Code coverage and profiling for Cascades based applications

Tags: code-coverage, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I would like to run my Blackberry 10 Cascades application with code coverage and profiler. To my wonder when I create Blackberry 10 Cascades application the IDE does not give any option for building it with Code Coverage or Profiler as it gives with Library or Native application.

I am not sure if it is even possible. I tried to dig into Blackberry documentation but have not found any clues.

Please let me know what if it is possible what I might be missing.

Comment: @Abdullag: What code coverage exactly?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Code coverage tool provided bu the QNX IDE for Blackberry development

Comment: You mean Momentics, or QtCreator?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I mean QNX Momentics IDE.

Comment: QML, C++, or mixed application?

Comment: Mixed i.e QML + C++. I created a Cascade application using the IDE Wizard. This application does not give me build option for Code Coverage and Profiling.

Comment: Which version are you using just in case?

Comment: Version: 10.2.1
Build id: v201308081807